# Random variable as an integral of an indicator function

Tags: pr.probability, measure-theory, integration

[This answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/295742/501568) says that if $X$ is a random variable and $X_+ = \mathrm{max}(0, X)$, then $X_+ = \int_0^\infty I_{\{X > x\}}\mathrm{d}x$. I'd like to know how to derive this starting with $A \in \mathcal{S} \implies \int_S 1_A\mathrm{d}\mu = \mu(A)$ (from ["Desired Properties"](https://stats.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Probability_Theory/Probability_Mathematical_Statistics_and_Stochastic_Processes_(Siegrist)/03:_Distributions/3.10:_The_Integral_With_Respect_to_a_Measure)).

My thinking is that for a probability space $(\Omega, F, \mu)$, $\{X > t\} \in F \implies \int_\Omega I_{\{X > t\}}\mathrm{d}\mu = \mu(\{X > t\})$ but it's the wrong variable of integration. Am I on the right track?

Comment: Does max(0, X) mean max{0, X}, i.e., the larger of X and 0 ?

Comment: Equality $X_+ = \int_0^\infty I_{\{X > x\}}\mathrm{d}x$ is obvious and is an equality between random variables. It cannot follow from equalities between expectations. Moreover, Mathoverflow is devoted to questions about research.

Comment: Just to amplify what Christophe said: $y_+=\int_0^\infty I_{\{y>x\}}\mathrm{d}x$ is simply true for any real number $y$. There is nothing special involving random variables going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The layer cake representation of a non-negative  measurable function, $X$, is applied in the proof of proposition 2.1 [here](https://stat.uiowa.edu/sites/stat.uiowa.edu/files/cae/Lo_Expectation.pdf).